# How to configure Public instance permanently?

Tags: configuration, magnolia

I am changing the Magnolia instance to public instance by doing configuration following the wiki. 
Whenever the server restarts or install the configuration is being vanished.

How to make the configure permanent so that we no need to configure it again and again while restart or install the sever.

Can anyone suggest ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

go to the magnolia.properties file and set magnolia.bootstrap.authorInstance=false

Comment: we are generating an war file and deploying it in the external apache Tomcat server. So where I need to change the key in Default or in magnliaPublic folder.

Comment: you mean which file under the config folder? https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Configuration+management#Configurationmanagement-Customization

Comment: /WEB-INF/config/default for default, while /WEB-INF/config/<server-name> for specific server configuration

Answer (score 0):

Configuration should be permanent once you have changed it. If it changes back after restart, it's either because you lost or otherwise removed or deleted your repo (in which case you have much bigger problem then switching author to public) and are reinstalling it or something else in your setup is causing reinitialisation of the system.
You should be also able to already install it as permanent w/o having to change anything afterwards. See documentation for more details on that in [here](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Configuration+management) and [here](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/WAR+file+with+multiple+configurations).